# Codeigniter composer_autoload gives 500 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, rabbitmq, codeigniter-3

Below is `config.php` file:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';
function __autoload($class){
    if($class == "MY_Controller0"){
        @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . '.php' );
    }
}
```

When I remove `__autoload` function it's working fine. With that function getting `HTTP ERROR 500`.

In vendor there is a codeigniter-rabbitmq-library.
How can I run rabbitmq library along with existing code?

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller0' not found in /var/www/my_app/public_html/application/controllers/process/method.php on line 3

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: @aynber: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MY_Controller0' not found in /var/www/my_app/public_html/application/controllers/process/method.php on line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CodeIgniter 3 the `$config['composer_autoload']` value is a boolean. Does not need a path.
The function __autoload in deprecated. Maybe:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
if ($class === 'MY_Controller0') {
    if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . '.php')) {
        include_once $file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, entering a path is working, because it is casted in boolean, and it equals true, as it is not empty.